# Java incompatibility between versions

Tags: windows-7, java

I run software on my PC that works great on Java v6u32 and Java v7u25, but my PC ran automatic Java updates and updates my Java to a newer version than v7u25, which was what I had.

The software is basically driver software for a USB token - For the token software to be recognised, the right Java needs to be installed.

Since the update to a newer Java version which is not officially supported by the token software, the USB token does not detect the token software anymore.

Even if I uninstall the latest Java and reinstall the older supported version of Java, it still does not work.

**My question**: How do I revert back to the previous Java configuration after a new version is installed?

Comment: You do understand that the current version of Java 7 isn't `Update 25` right? Any software that worked with Update 25 has to work with `Update 45`.  We have no idea how this custom software detects your installed Java installation.  As new versions of Java are installed the previous Updates are kept installed at least on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to do a System Restore on Windows to before the update.  Be careful this may also undo any other changes that has been made to the PC, like Windows service packs or other updated drivers.

Comment: Any other way than that?

Comment: @DextrousDave.  That is the sledgehammer way of doing it.  You can also look for a cleanup program like CleanUp[link] http://download.cnet.com/CleanUp/3000-2144_4-10727454.html or RegClean  [link]http://regclean-pro.en.softonic.com/  I am not favourable to any of the 2.  Have seen that they at time can do more harm than good.

Comment: ok cool, thank you. I thought there was a more specific and direct way of doing it.